# Reference or example using SkinId with TMS Intraweb Components

Tags: intraweb

There is a property in the TIWDBAdvWebGrid component called SkinId.  I wasn't able to find documentation for it, and wonder if the TMS Intraweb components are skinnable, and if so, how its done.  Any link to documentation or brief explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that skins are not supported with Intraweb at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Visit [CGDevTools](http://www.cgdevtools.com) they have a jQuery components suite to use with Intraweb all with theme support for professional skin user interface.